# How to boot a FreeBSD 11 image on a Raspberry PI B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, freebsd

I downloaded the latest FreeBSD snapshot image for the Raspberry PI B model (FreeBSD-11.0-CURRENT-arm-armv6-RPI-B-20141222-r276066.img) from the official FreeBSD ftp.

I copied the image to the SD card using the program Disk Image Writer on Ubuntu. 
After plugging in the SD card to the RPI and switching it on, the FreeBSD kernel gets not loaded. The last message on the monitor is always:
kernel entry at 0x100100...
kernel args: (null)

Using an FreeBSD 10 image instead works fine. Does anybody experience the same issue?
Does anybody have an idea what I did wrong?

Thank you all!
Jo

Comment: You should probably ask this on the `freebsd-arm` mailing list.

Comment: Ok, I will follow your suggestion and ask for help on the freebsd-arm mailing list. Thanks